# reuse the one fragment in other tabs also I want to build UI Dynamically for different tabs without inflating XML

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-framelayout

I am doing my first app in which, I use fragments for tabs . in this I want to reuse the one fragment in other tabs also I want to build UI Dynamically for different tabs without inflating XML  [The Screen shot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8HHW.jpg)

Code inside the Activity Looks like this

```
public class Schedules extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedules);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentOne(), "SCIENCE");
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentOne(), "SOCIAL");
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentOne(), "ENGLISH");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentDays = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTimings = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);

        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

and code inside the fragment goes here

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment{

    LinearLayout lLayout;
    TextView tView;

    public FragmentOne() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While reusing fragment it should meet certain criteria, that its follows the same context, what I mean is appearance would be same but depending on data provided to the Fragment it's UI and information displayed would change,

If your fragments have completely different UI and Data structure provided to that fragment, it would have to deal with different scenarios in which it has to work differently, that would increase your code overhead in the same fragment. in this case you are better off making two different fragments.

If you insist on reusing the fragment, you can create an instance of that fragment(`MyFragment`) you want to reuse and populate internal UI and data depending on the data and type you are providing, Kindly notice this will only increase your work.

```
MyFragment.newInstance("English","data");

MyFragment.newInstance("Social","data");

MyFragment.newInstance("Science","data");
```

MyFragment would look something like this

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

public MyFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static MyFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    if (param1.equalsIgnoreCase("ENGLISH")) {
        //THIS IS INSTANCE OF ENGLISH TYPE DATA
    } else if (param1.equalsIgnoreCase("SCIENCE")) {
        //THIS IS INSTANCE OF SCIENCE TYPE DATA
    }else if (param1.equalsIgnoreCase("SOCIAL")) {
        //THIS IS INSTANCE OF SOCIAL TYPE DATA
    }
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

you would have to make conditions in `onCreateView` and `onActivityCreated` methods to make use of fragment appropriately depending on the type of data provided to this fragment

Comment: I tried to implement, but didn't materialize hence, I decided to programmatically build UI inside fragment, if someone has any link please give me the link, which would be immensely helpful

Comment: @Naveen, try to understand how factory method works, It would help you instantiate Object with data you want to show so you can take the decision in the code about changing UI. You can use LayoutInflater multiple times to inflate layout in your code